# How to put emojis (images) on nodes

Tags: emoji, gephi

I just made a Twitter network analysis using the Twitter Streaming Importer, on Emoji Network logic.

Problem is, the emojis are only shown as a text, but I want them to be shown like images. Like this: https://mailchimp.com/resources/mailchimps-most-popular-subject-line-emojis/

I've already downloaded the Image Preview plugin, but I'm not able to link the image to the label name.

Please help

Comment: how can we help when you dont even show what your code looks like.

Comment: Gephi doesn't show any code, but it uses a plugin instead. I've read that if you name the images as the label of the node, it will automatically get the .jpg/.png associated with the UTF emoji name and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt an answer although not 100% sure. this is the right answer. The MailChimp guys might be showing some icons instead of pictures and it's a pitty they don't share the Gephi file. What I have tried and works to some extend is the following

1. generated the emoji with Ms Word, after using the instructions [here](https://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm), **Method 4**,
2. copied the emoji from Word to the *Label* field in Gephi,
3. from the *Preview* tab of Gephi, I selected **Segoe UI Symbol 12** as a font,
4. Checked *"Show labels"* at the left pane,
5. Clicked *Refresh*

I got this:

[image]

Comment: I did that, but it showed the same as you. And I'm not looking for ASCII symbols. They literally show .png instead of characters. That's what I'm trying to solve and I don't have any clue how to do it!